# A template to call a function with arguments from an iterator

Tags: c++

I am trying to come up with a template to call functions with arguments generated from iterators. Here is an example:

```
// These are some functions to be called.
void f(int x) { ... }
void f(int x, int y) { ... }
void f(int x, int y, int z) { ... }

// This is a template to call functions.
template<typename I, size_t n> void apply(I iterator) {
  int a_1 = *iterator;
  int a_2 = *++iterator;
  ...
  int a_n = *++iterator;
  f(a_1, a_2,...a_n);
}

// This is an example of a function call.
apply<iterator, 2>(i);
```

If my iterator is a random access iterator then this task can be accomplished as this:

```
template<typename I, size_t ...a> void apply(I iterator) {
  f(*(iterator + a)...);
}

apply<iterator, 0, 1>(i);
```

I wonder if there is a way to accomplish this task for a plain [input iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might do something like:

```
template <typename It, size_t ...Is>
decltype(auto) apply_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>, It& iterator) {
    decltype(*iterator) values[] = {(static_cast<void>(Is), *iterator++)...};
    return f(values[Is]...);
}

template <size_t N, typename It>
decltype(auto) apply(It& iterator) {
    return apply_impl(std::make_index_sequence<N>(), iterator);
}
```

Note: Evaluation order in function call is not guarantied, so

```
f((Is, *iterator++)...); // Incorrect, even in C++17
```

but evaluation order is left to right in initializer_list.

Comment: good solution. It might be worth a note explaining why it's necessary to pass the argument values through the array.

Comment: @RichardHodges: Note added.